# Other word for 'spiel'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing an English essay about Shakespeare.

The sentence(s) I am having trouble with:

> We've read it, we've heard it, we've seen it. We know the Shakespeare spiel.

The difficulty I am having and what I've tried:

I don't know whether 'spiel' is an appropriate word. I've tried replacing it with the word 'deal' as well (e.g. We know the deal with teenagers in modern society), but it just doesn't seem to work. These are the two opening sentences of my essay and I need something that hooks the reader. Can you suggest any better words for 'spiel'?

Comment: *"Spiel"* means literally "play" (and for instance "actor" is *Schauspieler.)* I'm not going to propose that as a proper answer but maybe you could make a useful pun out of this.

Comment: Are you writing a poem? That has a lovely rhythm as written.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the element of society of which you are a part (denoted by 'We') have read, heard and seen Shakespeare's work and also been exposed to the explanations, and perhaps the hype, about the greatness of the man and his work presented by your teachers and others? If that's what you are saying then I think 'spiel' is just right because 'spiel', to me means glib, formulaic, practiced speech intended to persuade. Sales talk in fact.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spiel

Comment: In British English, "spiel" (from the Yiddish) is informal and thus may not be suitable for an essay.

Answer (score 2):

As "spiel" is usually disapproving, it is probably better that you decided to avoid it. Whereas "spiel" connotes the idea of persuasive talk, "deal" connotes that of "arrangement"; we must presume that an arrangement of ideas is the concept intended and if that is the basis for persuasive talk there is not yet contained in this term the reference to persuasion, which, apparently, is an important notion to preserve. Accordingly, "deal" does not appear to be an ideal replacement. A term that has none of the defects of the two examined is the formal "**rhetoric**" (the skill of using language in speech or writing in a special way that influences or entertains people (*Shorter OED*)).

- We've read it, we've heard it, we've seen it. We know the Shakespeare rhetoric.

There is an ample use of the term "rhetoric of Shakespeare" in the literature ([criticism](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_start=1800&content=rhetoric+of+Shakespeare%2CShakespeare+rhetoric&year_end=2008&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crhetoric%20of%20Shakespeare%3B%2Cc0)) whereas "Shakespeare rhetoric" has no currency and therefore you might prefer, if opting for this replacement, to use the usual term.

- We've read it, we've heard it, we've seen it. We know the rhetoric of Shakespeare.

Comment: What if the OP wants to say something (mildly) disparaging about Shakespeare?

Comment: @jsw29 Can a global judgement about this author be made that'll be diparaging, even if mildly? Some went as far as to charge him with antisemitism, yet the argument is thin and does not extend its grip further than "*The Merchant of Venice*"… Here, it is a question of the whole art of this dramatist and the criticism isn't mild, that would be discrediting his work wholly, which nobody has ever done. Of course, there might exist such a position but it seems unthinkable. People blasé about this oeuvre often content themselves with the mere assertion that there is not in it as much as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

How about **line**? From Cambridge:

> **[line](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line)**: a way of dealing with or thinking about something or someone

Your example:

> We've read it, we've heard it, we've seen it. We know the Shakespeare **line**.

**Line** here communicates the sense that educators and others follow pretty much the same line when it comes to the significance of Shakespeare and his work. It sounds to me that you might want to take issue with that in your essay. If so, you could also consider **party line**, where the "party" here would correspond to those who've drunk the Shakespeare Kool-Aid.

As per Lexico, a **[spiel](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/spiel)** is an elaborate or glib speech or story, typically one used by a salesperson (UK), or a long or fast speech or story, typically one intended as a means of persuasion or as an excuse but regarded with skepticism or contempt by those who hear it (US). **Line** means a way of thinking about something, in your case Shakespeare. It is not an elaborate, glib, long, or fast speech or story; is not primarily intended to persuade; and is not generally regarded with skepticism or contempt by those who hear it -- it's not a sales job. In these senses, it would seem that **line** works better than **spiel**.

Comment: Yes, this  is a good alternative to *spiel*, but it might be a good idea to make it explicit what are its advantages over *spiel*.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for the comment and suggestion. Done.